# Action Controller Exception w/ building "Multiple files upload with nested resource using Paperclip in Rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to implement this rails cook solution for multiple images found [here](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/) and am having issues with an action controller exception.  I'm sure it's something I have over looked.

Here are my .rb files:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename"

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end 

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And my pictures controller

```
  class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_picture, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pictures
  # GET /pictures.json
  def index
    @pictures = Picture.all
  end

  # GET /pictures/1
  # GET /pictures/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pictures/new
  def new
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  # GET /pictures/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pictures
  # POST /pictures.json
  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
     @document = Document.new(:name) # :name is a symbol, not

    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.save
        format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @picture }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pictures/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pictures/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.update(picture_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @picture }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pictures/1
  # DELETE /pictures/1.json
  def destroy
    @picture.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pictures_url, notice: 'Picture was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_picture
      @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def picture_params
      params[:picture]
    end
end
```

And here is my form

```
    <!-- app/views/galleries/_form.html.erb -->
<%= form_for @gallery, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :description, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :pictures, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <!-- The magic is coming ...look at my eyes....shazammmm -->
      <!-- Use HTML5 multiple attribute to enable multiple selection
           and pass back to controller all files as an array, ready
           for paperclip!!
           file_field_tag, since images is not a gallery attribute
       -->
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                galleries_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is my gallery controller

```
 class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /galleries
  # GET /galleries.json
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  # GET /galleries/1
  # GET /galleries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /galleries/new
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  # GET /galleries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /galleries
  # POST /galleries.json
  def create
  @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @gallery.save

      if params[:images]
        #===== The magic is here ;)
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @gallery.pictures.create(image: image)
        }
      end

      format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /galleries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /galleries/1
  # DELETE /galleries/1.json
  def destroy
    @gallery.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to galleries_url, notice: 'Gallery was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gallery
      @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:gallery_id, :picture)
    end
end
```

And here is my error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `picture_params` method may be causing the problem. Try modifying it to use the following format:

```
def picture_params
  params.require(:picture).permit(:whitelisted, :attributes, :placed, :here)
end
```

You can use [this repo](https://github.com/hackhowtofaq/multiple_file_upload_paperclip_rails/blob/master/app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb) provided in the tutorial you're following as a reference.

An additional reference on [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Zoran. . . I changed picture_params to this   

def picture_params
      params.require[:picture].permit(:gallery_id, :image)
   end

still not working though.  Now getting, "ArgumentError in PicturesController#update
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Comment: Ahh ok - you're using brackets on `require[:picture]`, it should use parenthesis. Hope that helps!

Comment: I saw that and changed it when I referenced the repo.  Now I get. . ."param is missing or the value is empty: picture"

Comment: How does your form look?

Comment: Added the form to the question above

Comment: Your form seems to be fine. Can you post your GalleryController as well?

Comment: Ok - so the `gallery_params` should also be changed to the strong params format. See if that helps.

Comment: Updated the post with current error & gallery controller.  adding the params didn't work though.

Comment: Interesting. Does your pictures_form have `form_for [@gallery, @picture]` instead of just `@picture`? I may be reaching, but maybe the params are not being constructed in the right format when passed via the form.